# Night/Dark mode for the App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

That'd save us some battery while being nice on the eyes at night. I love the black interface that *reddit is fun* app has and would love to see same on this app. Thanks.

Comment: @ifajra that appears to be for the main site; this request is for the android app. Not a dupe.

Comment: yup sorry ddn't know how to search from the mobile app. just clicked on request feature button. i should probably delete it. Edit: oh not a dup. alright. :)

Comment: Or possibly a read-easy mode too like the "reading mode" provided on samsung tablets, where everything is tinted a reddish color?

Comment: @DaM approved your edit, but it's still a dupe... ;)