# Night/dark mode for iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It would be great if there was a dark theme for the iOS app.  It would make reading readier on the eyes, especially at night.

This is not a dupe of [Night/Dark mode for the App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284973/night-dark-mode-for-the-app) or [Let us choose a different theme for the android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278407/let-us-choose-a-different-theme-for-the-app), as both of those are for the Android app.

Comment: @NathanTuggy this request is for ios-app, not for android-app, as suggested in dups.

Comment: The duplicate is nonetheless valid. I see no point in having two separate feature requests, one for iOS and one for Android.

Comment: @Glorfindel I do.  They are two separate apps with separate codebases.  Filling the request for one app would not necessarily fill the request for the other.

Comment: I see your point, but we'll be getting a lot of duplicate content on Meta that way. Basically every FR for one of the apps can become a new question for the other app.

Comment: @Glorfindel But that shouldn't matter if each post is valid.  It wouldn't make sense to mark a feature request for both as completed if it only was implemented on one platform. I think that would cause more confusion than having duplicate feature requests for each platform.

Comment: @Glorfindel that's already what happens, there are plenty of duplicate FRs for Android/iOS

Comment: Well, that's a shame, then :( The [status-completed] is about the only positive thing I see about having two separate FRs.

Comment: Looks like both apps are discontinued, it's been almost a full year since anything was done with the android app, and several months since bugs were fixed for iOS app. So, personally I won't bother to report any bugs or ask for new features as it's just waste of time.

Comment: Anyway agree it's not a duplicate, used hammer to clear the pending votes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [last question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285833/339911) with [tag:status-completed] and [tag:ios-app] was about 2 months ago. No too much, but it would be less.

Comment: @ale that is what he said: only bugs are fixed and the last one was months ago. There is no active development if you fix one bug in two months.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It appears your comment came too soon, Brian just responded to a couple of the iOS questions.

Comment: @Catija rare case where I'm happy to be wrong... I can just hope same will happen with android app, though I highly doubt it.

Comment: Does anyone know what is the status of this FR?